# Dynamic data with Flask and Mongodb data

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, dynamic, frontend

I am a beginner in Flask. Instead of static data delivery (due to size) I would like to make database calls based on the interactions (queries) of the end-user in the frontend. 
I can't find any example on the net about how to proceed. I have been thinking about something like:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.before_first_request
def initialize_database():
    pass

@app.route('api/data')
def get_data_by_selecting_bounding_box():
    pass
```

data are tweets and the user shall be able to select an area (bounding-box) on a map and get back a response retrieved from the Mongodb database of data included in the area.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a few problems to solve:

1. Manage the db connection.
2. Query the DB
3. Return the result

Let's start with the mongo connection:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient(URI_STRING)
```

Here you establish the mongodb client with pymongo. Now you can access your db on the mongodb service as:

```
db = client["my-DB-name"]
```

From here, you can access collections like your collection of locations, which I will assume is called `locations`. You can access it like `db.locations.find(...)`

Now you need to query the db. Your API needs to accept `lat1, lat2, long1, long2` to represent the bounds of the bounding box. Here I'm going to assume they are `.args` as described in the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#the-request-object)

```
@app.route('api/data')
def get_data_by_selecting_bounding_box():
    cursor = db.locations.find(
    "$and":[
    {"lat": {"$gt": requests.args.get("lat1", 0)}},
    {"lat": {"$lt": requests.args.get("lat2", 0)}},
    {"long": {"$gt": requests.args.get("long1", 0)}},
    {"long": {"$lt": requests.args.get("long2", 0)}}
    ])
```

Now you can `return` the cursor at the end of this route handler, in whatever manner your `html` template calls for. It could be as simple as:

```
    return [doc for docs in cursor]
```